# Is it possible to run webpack configs sequentially, one after another, not in parallel, and use output of previous config as an entry for next one?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, build, config

As in the question, is it possible?

This is my `webpack.config.js`:

```
const CssMinimizerPlugin = require('css-minimizer-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const path = require('path');
const TerserPlugin = require('terser-webpack-plugin');

const generateHtmlPlugin = (chunks, filename, inject, template, templateParameters) => {
  return new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    chunks,
    filename,
    inject,
    template,
    templateParameters
  });
}

const multipleModulesTemplatesArray = [
  {
    filename: 'egm_mm_wrapper_bottom_banner.html',
    inject: 'head',
    template: 'src/html/template.ejs',
    templateParameters: {
      bodyClass: 'egm_mm_wrapper_bottom_banner',
      htmlClass: 'egm_mm_wrapper_bottom_banner',
      initConsoleLog: 'MMWrapperBottom start'
    }
  },
  {
    filename: 'egm_mm_wrapper_overhead_display.html',
    inject: 'head',
    template: 'src/html/template.ejs',
    templateParameters: {
      bodyClass: 'egm_mm_wrapper_overhead_display',
      htmlClass: 'egm_mm_wrapper_overhead_display',
      initConsoleLog: 'MMWrapperOverhead start'
    }
  },
  {
    filename: 'ilink_media_scheduler.html',
    inject: 'head',
    template: 'src/html/template.ejs',
    templateParameters: {
      bodyClass: 'ilink_media_scheduler',
      htmlClass: 'ilink_media_scheduler',
      initConsoleLog: 'WMiLink.MediaScheduler start'
    }
  },
  {
    filename: 'ilink_window_manager.html',
    inject: 'head',
    template: 'src/html/template.ejs',
    templateParameters: {
      bodyClass: 'ilink_window_manager',
      htmlClass: 'ilink_window_manager',
      initConsoleLog: 'WMiLink.WindowManager start'
    }
  }
];

const populateHtmlPlugins = (pagesArray) => {
  const result = [];
  pagesArray.forEach(page => {
    result.push(generateHtmlPlugin(page.chunks, page.filename, page.inject, page.template, page.templateParameters));
  })
  return result;
}

const templates = populateHtmlPlugins(multipleModulesTemplatesArray);

const commonsAndVendorsConfig = {
  context: path.resolve(__dirname, '.'),
  devServer: {
    client: {
      logging: 'verbose',
      overlay: true,
    },
    static: {
      directory: path.join(__dirname, './dist'),
    },
    compress: true,
    port: 9001,
  },
  entry: [
    '../shared_libs/modules/vendors.js',
    '../shared_libs/modules/commons.js',
    './src/js/egm_mm_wrapper_commons.js',
    './src/js/ilink_commons.js',
  ],
  mode: 'production',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        options: {
          presets: [
              '@babel/preset-env'
          ]
        },
        test: /\.js$/
      }
    ]
  },
  name: 'commons-and-vendors',
  optimization: {
    minimize: true,
    minimizer: [
      new TerserPlugin({
        extractComments: false,
        terserOptions: {
          ecma: 5,
          format: {
            comments: false,
          },
          mangle: {
            toplevel: true
          },
          module: true
        },
      }),
    ]
  },
  output: {
    filename: 'commons_and_vendors.[contenthash].js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    publicPath: '/'
  },
  performance: {
    maxEntrypointSize: 512000,
    maxAssetSize: 512000
  },
  target: 'web'
};

const multipleModulesConfig = {
  context: path.resolve(__dirname, '.'),
  dependencies: ['commons-and-vendors'],
  devServer: {
    client: {
      logging: 'verbose',
      overlay: true,
    },
    static: {
      directory: path.join(__dirname, './dist'),
    },
    compress: true,
    port: 9001,
  },
  entry: {
    egm_mm_wrapper_bottom_banner: './modules/egm_mm_wrapper_bottom_banner.js',
    egm_mm_wrapper_overhead_display: './modules/egm_mm_wrapper_overhead_display.js',
    ilink_media_scheduler: './modules/ilink_media_scheduler.js',
    ilink_window_manager: './modules/ilink_window_manager.js'
  },
  mode: 'production',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        options: {
          presets: [
            ['@babel/preset-env']
          ]
        },
        test: /\.js$/
      },
      {
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
        use: [
          'css-loader',
          'sass-loader'
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/i,
        loader: 'html-loader',
        options: {
          minimize: true
        },
      },
    ]
  },
  name: 'multiple-modules',
  optimization: {
    minimize: true,
    minimizer: [
      new CssMinimizerPlugin({
        test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i
      }),
      new TerserPlugin({
        extractComments: false,
        terserOptions: {
          ecma: 5,
          format: {
            comments: false,
          },
          mangle: {
            toplevel: true
          },
          module: true
        },
      }),
    ]
  },
  output: {
    filename: '[name].[contenthash].js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    publicPath: '/'
  },
  performance: {
    maxEntrypointSize: 512000,
    maxAssetSize: 512000
  },
  plugins: templates,
  target: 'web'
};

const singleModuleConfig = {
    context: path.resolve(__dirname, '.'),
    dependencies: ['multiple-modules'],
    devServer: {
        client: {
            logging: 'verbose',
            overlay: true,
        },
        static: {
            directory: path.join(__dirname, './dist'),
        },
        compress: true,
        port: 9001,
    },
    entry: './modules/mma.js',
    mode: 'production',
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                options: {
                    presets: [
                        ['@babel/preset-env']
                    ]
                },
                test: /\.js$/
            },
            {
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: 'html-loader',
                options: {
                    minimize: true
                },
                test: /\.html$/
            },
        ]
    },
    name: 'mma',
    optimization: {
        minimize: true,
        minimizer: [
            new TerserPlugin({
                extractComments: false,
                terserOptions: {
                    ecma: 5,
                    format: {
                        comments: false,
                    },
                    mangle: {
                        toplevel: true
                    },
                    module: true
                },
            }),
        ]
    },
    output: {
        clean: true,
        filename: '[name].[contenthash].js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        publicPath: '/'
    },
    performance: {
        maxEntrypointSize: 512000,
        maxAssetSize: 512000
    },
    target: 'web'
};

module.exports = [commonsAndVendorsConfig, multipleModulesConfig, singleModuleConfig];
module.exports.parallelism = 1;
```

This is my `template.ejs` file:

```
<html class="<%= htmlClass %>">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'/>
    <title>Window Manager</title>

    <script type='application/javascript'>
        console.log('<%= initConsoleLog %>');
    </script>
</head>

<body class="<%= bodyClass %>">
    <div class="mmContentContainer"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

And here's my `mma.js` file:

```
import '../dist/commons_and_vendors';

import '../dist/egm_mm_wrapper_bottom_banner';
import '../dist/egm_mm_wrapper_overhead_display';
import '../dist/ilink_media_scheduler';
import '../dist/ilink_window_manager';

import egm_mm_wrapper_bottom_banner from '../dist/egm_mm_wrapper_bottom_banner.html';
import egm_mm_wrapper_overhead_display from '../dist/egm_mm_wrapper_overhead_display.html';
import ilink_media_scheduler from '../dist/ilink_media_scheduler.html';
import ilink_window_manager from '../dist/ilink_window_manager.html';
```

And when I run the webpack build, I get the error:

```
 ERROR in ./modules/mma.js 47:0-37
  Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../dist/commons_and_vendors' in 'C:\Users\user\Projects\multimedia_advertisement\modules'

  ERROR in ./modules/mma.js 48:0-46
  Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../dist/egm_mm_wrapper_bottom_banner' in 'C:\Users\user\Projects\multimedia_advertisement\modules'

  ERROR in ./modules/mma.js 49:0-49
  Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../dist/egm_mm_wrapper_overhead_display' in 'C:\Users\user\Projects\multimedia_advertisement\modules'

  ERROR in ./modules/mma.js 50:0-39
  Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../dist/ilink_media_scheduler' in 'C:\Users\user\Projects\multimedia_advertisement\modules'

  ERROR in ./modules/mma.js 51:0-38
  Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../dist/ilink_window_manager' in 'C:\Users\user\Projects\multimedia_advertisement\modules'

  ERROR in ./modules/mma.js 52:0-85
  Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../dist/egm_mm_wrapper_bottom_banner.html' in 'C:\Users\user\Projects\multimedia_advertisement\modules'

  ERROR in ./modules/mma.js 53:0-91
  Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../dist/egm_mm_wrapper_overhead_display.html' in 'C:\Users\user\Projects\multimedia_advertisement\modules'

  ERROR in ./modules/mma.js 54:0-71
  Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../dist/ilink_media_scheduler.html' in 'C:\Users\user\Projects\multimedia_advertisement\modules'

  ERROR in ./modules/mma.js 55:0-69
  Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../dist/ilink_window_manager.html' in 'C:\Users\user\Projects\multimedia_advertisement\modules'

  9 errors have detailed information that is not shown.
  Use 'stats.errorDetails: true' resp. '--stats-error-details' to show it.
```

When I run webpack build with the above suggested flag `--stats-error-details`, I get among other errors such an error:

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../dist/egm_mm_wrapper_overhead_display.html' in 'C:\Users\user\Project\multimedia_advertisement\modules'
  resolve '../dist/egm_mm_wrapper_overhead_display.html' in 'C:\Users\user\Project\multimedia_advertisement\modules'
    using description file: C:\Users\user\Project\multimedia_advertisement\package.json (relative path: ./modules)
      Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
      using description file: C:\Users\user\Project\multimedia_advertisement\package.json (relative path: ./dist/egm_mm_wrapper_overhead_display.html)
        no extension
          Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
          C:\Users\user\Project\multimedia_advertisement\dist\egm_mm_wrapper_overhead_display.html doesn't exist
        .js
          Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
          C:\Users\user\Project\multimedia_advertisement\dist\egm_mm_wrapper_overhead_display.html.js doesn't exist
        .json
          Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
          C:\Users\user\Project\multimedia_advertisement\dist\egm_mm_wrapper_overhead_display.html.json doesn't exist
        .wasm
          Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
          C:\Users\user\Project\multimedia_advertisement\dist\egm_mm_wrapper_overhead_display.html.wasm doesn't exist
        as directory
          C:\Users\user\Project\multimedia_advertisement\dist\egm_mm_wrapper_overhead_display.html doesn't exist
```

Even adding the `module.exports.parallelism = 1;` doesn't help.

On the side note, in error messsage we can see something like `ERROR in ./modules/mma.js 50:0-39`, the line number is such, because I have commented code before the current used code.

If I delete it and put in the `mma.js` file only the needed code, the same errors persist.

Did anyone stumbled upon potential solution regarding sequential code running?